# CSS: Auto stretch div to fit available horizontal space

Tags: css, width

How can I style a div with CSS to automatically fit in a gap? At the moment, I have something like this

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="auto-width"></div>
    <div id="changing-width"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    padding: 30px;
}

#wrapper * {
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#auto-width {
    width: 271px; /*I don't want to have to set this value*/
}

#changing-width {
    width: 140px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

I want the div with the ID "auto-width" to change it's width based on the padding of the wrapper, and the width and margin of the "changing-width" div. I don't mind using the padding and margin values, but in my actual project, the width of the "changing-width" div actually changes depending on the amount text in it and I want to "auto-width" div to change with it.

JSFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/bve8162f/

Comment: From one tumbleweed to another - I'm not sure, but you may take a look at `width: calc()`. Can you explain a little more about the constraints of your layout? `Width` is notoriously tricky in css, but there may be a different solution from what you seem to want. I'll take a closer look at this one later.

Comment: I just want the left div to be as long as possible based on of the width of the right div, without defining the width of the right div, because it will stretch on its own.

Answer (score 1):

If the width of the right div is fixed, then you could set the width of the left div like so:

```
#auto-width {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

...where the `200px` is the width of your right div plus the padding. If you're using a css preprocessor like Less or Sass, you could create a variable so you can define the value in one place for both styles.

Note that the `100%` refers to the explicit width of the parent. This solution seemed to work in your fiddle ([updated version here](https://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/bve8162f/1/),) but if your production code is set up a little differently, this may not work. I'll see if I can stumble across a different way, but this is one method I personally like to use when I can.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, unfortunately, my fiddle was a little deceiving I guess. I will probably use this fact a lot later on, so thank you, but in this example, the width of the right div wasn't going to be set either, it would change depending on what text was in it, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bve8162f/2/ As the text changes, so will the width of the green div, and I wanted the red div to always be the right width accordingly, but I'm beginning to think it's either impossible or would take a bit of JQuery/JavaScript.